# Python Class Attribute Error 'Event' has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I created a code as a collaboration for a game a few friends and I are making for fun, and I am a complete noob at python. I created a class for a battle arena as part of the game:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()



class battle:

    def __init__(self, MonHealth):
        self.Distance = 10
        self.Center = 5
        self.MonHealth = MonHealth
    def LEFT1(self):
        if self.Center < 20:
            self.Distance += 1
            distance = abs(self.Distance)
            self.Center += 1
            center = abs(self.Center)
            print (str(distance) + " meters" + "    " + str(center) + " meters")
    def right1(self):
        if self.Center > -20:
            self.Distance -= 1
            self.Center -= 1
            center = abs(self.Center)
            distance = abs(self.Distance)
            print (str(distance) + " meters" + "    " + str(center) + " meters")
    def Lunge1(self):
        hit = [0,1,2,3,4]
        random.shuffle(hit)
        if abs(self.Distance) <= 1 and hit[0] >= 2:
            print ("strike")
            self.MonHealth -= 10
            if self.MonHealth < 0:
                print ("YOU WIN")
        elif abs(self.Distance) <= 1:
            print ("blocked")
        else:
            print ("miss")
    def block1(self):
        print ("blocked enemy")




    root.bind("<Left>", LEFT1)

    root.bind("<Right>", right1)

    root.bind("<Return>", Lunge1)

    root.bind("<Shift_L>", block1)
```

When I run the class, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'Center'

How do I fix this problem?

I read other explanations and solutions about/for attribute errors, but they were all about 'str' objects.

As a side note, if I delete 'Center' entirely, it gives me the same error for MonHealth. I think I just completely screwed up this code, but is there any way to salvage it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your class wrongly. You have ti initialize it first:

```
a=battle(45) # you can use any number you want instead of 45
```

Then you have to `bind` as follows:

```
root.bind("<Left>", a.LEFT1)

root.bind("<Right>", a.right1)

root.bind("<Return>", a.Lunge1)

root.bind("<Shift_L>", a.block1)
```

You can also decorate your class's methods as `@classmethod`, but it won't make much sense in your case as you'll still have to initialize the `self.MonHealth` variable.